# how to maintain a session in android and how to set a session timeout?

Tags: java, android, session, session-timeout

I have created a small `Pizza House Application`. I would like to have a `Session` and store the email address of the user and also **set session timed out** to it.

Could someone help me with it with a small example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many ways: 1) Shared Preferences and run a Service for timeout [Clear share Preferences while timeout occurs]. 2) Check Administration API's here [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#overview). 3) Use Account Manager.

Comment: this link help you http://androidexample.com/Android_Session_Management_Using_SharedPreferences_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=127&aaid=147

Answer (score 0):

you can manage this by using of shared preferences, also you can do this by creating database table,

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)